# golang sending json on multicast ip

Tags: arrays, json, go, multicast, gorilla

I'm writting a piece of Go to send json data on multicast udp:

```
func send(a string, messages chan interface{}) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", a)
    CheckError(err)
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)
    CheckError(err)
    for {
        msg := <-messages
        myjson, err := json.Marshal(msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error encoding JSON")
        return
        }
        //Write to bytes to multicast UDP
        c.Write([]byte(myjson))

        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

So my json is converted to an array of byte to make it work. Here is my "receiver" func:

```
func serveMulticastUDP(a string, messages chan interface{}) {

    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", a)
    CheckError(err)
    l, err := net.ListenMulticastUDP("udp", nil, addr)
    l.SetReadBuffer(maxDatagramSize)
    for {
        b := make([]byte, maxDatagramSize)
        n, src, err := l.ReadFromUDP(b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ReadFromUDP failed:", err)
        }
        s := string(b[:n])//here is my problem, I want s to be map[string]interface before sending in my channel
        messages<-s
        log.Println(s)
        log.Println(src)
        log.Println(n)
        //h(src, n, b)
    }
}
```

How can convert a array of bytes to map[string]interface (json) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you used [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) to convert your value to JSON text (`[]byte`).

The other direction (`[]byte` -> value) can be done using [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). `json.Unmarshal()` expects a `[]byte` so you don't even have to convert it to `string`.

See this example:

```
data := []byte(`{"key1":"value1","key2":123}`)

var m map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", m)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oCsqbTCX4L)):

```
map[key1:value1 key2:123]
```

**Notes:**

The result of marshaling (`json.Marshal()`) is a value of type `[]byte` so you don't need explicit conversion here:

```
c.Write([]byte(myjson))
```

You can simply write:

```
c.Write(myjson)
```

Also when unmarshaling, make sure you pass `b[:n]` to `json.Unmarshal()`, as the rest of the slice contains `0`s (which your 2nd error suggests) but they are not part of the json text!

Comment: Thank you icza, now I have another issue, it does panic when unmarshalling my byte array : unexpected end of json input. Should I open a new question with more details ?

Comment: That means the `[]byte` you're passing to `json.Unmarshal()` is not the complete JSON encoded text. It could be even empty. Make sure it contains the whole json text (check its content).

Comment: I understand (my json is quite huge vs UDP), could you suggest me a way to check the content properly ?

Comment: @r3dlight Just print it e.g. `fmt.Println(n, string(b[:n]), b[:n])`.

Comment: Ok, first I increased my maxDatagramSize to 18000. Then I made the print like you suggested : 16115 {...}[...] It seems to be complete but now I panic with panic: invalid character '\x00' after top-level value

Comment: @r3dlight Make sure you pass `b[:n]` to `json.Unmarshal()`, as the rest of the slice contains `0`s (which your error suggests) but they are not part of the json text!